# Disable meta+[letter] keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Relay with a built-in keyboard running CM11. I am trying to edit the keyboard layout, but some existing shortcuts are interfering with the new ones I am trying to add. For example:

/system/usr/keychars/sec_keypad.kcm:

```
key L {
    label:           'L'
    base:            'l'
    shift, capslock: 'L'
    meta:            '\''
    meta+shift:      '"'
}

key K {
    label:           'K'
    base:            'k'
    shift, capslock: 'K'
    meta:            ';'
    meta+shift:      ':'
}
```

When I press <kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, I get a semicolon as expected. However, <kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> mysteriously opens the Calendar app instead. Several other keys+<kbd>meta</kbd> open other apps as well. How can I disable these shortcuts?

Comment: Hello. Such questions are for [so]. We are a community for the **users** of Android and not developers.

Comment: @SarpSTA: Can you explain how is this question not relevant to an end-user but to a developer?